# ob_get_contents of a whole page in wordpress so I can change its contents then output

Tags: php, wordpress

This needs to be theme-unspecific, so writing a PHP/HTML template is not a solution.

I have a page that I have saved with these contents. The page id is 1103.

```
Some text
[pn_contents]
Some text
```

The page header contains the `<h1>` tag.

I have a function checking the URL for /pn/*, which I use to get the correct content.

When the URL is /pn/page1 I want the page title in the header, and the h1, to be "Page 1", and to replace replace `[pn_contents]` with some content that I can generate. Similarly when the URL is /pn/page2 I have different content to output.

I can replace the title, h1, and shortcodes with str_replace unless there's a better way, but I'm struggling to pull the WHOLE page from another URL. `get_post(1103);` gives me an object, but not the whole page.

How do I get page 1103 with header and footer so that I can change parts of it before outputting it?

Answer (score 0):

1. Add `<?php ob_start(); ?>` at first line of functions.php
2. Add `<?php do_action('put_this_in_last_of_footer'); ?>` in last line of footer.php , No line of code should be there after this.
3. Add this code to your functions.php

```
add_action('put_this_in_last_of_footer', function(){

   $content = ob_get_contents();

   ob_end_clean();

   //do some changes to content

   echo $content;

});
```

**`$content`** is your whole wordpress output, You can edit it.

Comment: Thanks but that's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Look, `$content` is HTML content of your output. From before **<html>** to **</html>**. You can modify it as you want to. If you want to restrict the code to some specific URL such as `/pn/*` you can do it with just an **`if( str_contains(get_permalink(), '/pn/') )`** statement, Or if you want to do something else please explain more.

Comment: I know that. It doesn't solve the problem given.

Answer (score 0):

May the *ugly* way (not tested) :

```
function get_the_html($post) {
    $post = get_post($post);
    $transient = get_transient('html-page-pn-'.$post->ID);

    if ($transient === false) {
        
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, get_permalink($post));
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 120);
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 120);
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);
        $value = curl_exec ($ch);

        set_transient('html-page-pn-'.$post->ID, $value, 24*60*60);;
    }


    return $value;
}
```